# winForm has no border shadow

Tags: c#, winforms, window, shadow

I want to create a blank border shadow form, and want to keep WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_CAPTION these three style style window use rise more convenient.

Currently used DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea to create shaded part. The shadow effect is present when the window is first created
[image]

But after minimizing, the shadow effect is gone
[image]

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : BorderlessForm.FormBase
    {
        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
        public static extern int DwmSetWindowAttribute(IntPtr hwnd, int attr, ref int attrValue, int attrSize);

        [DllImport("dwmapi.dll")]
        public static extern int DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(IntPtr hWnd, ref MARGINS pMarInset);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public enum WindowMessages
        {
            WM_NULL = 0x0000,
            WM_CREATE = 0x0001,
            WM_DESTROY = 0x0002,
            WM_MOVE = 0x0003,
            WM_SIZE = 0x0005,
            WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006,
            WM_SETFOCUS = 0x0007,
            WM_KILLFOCUS = 0x0008,
            WM_ENABLE = 0x000A,
            WM_SETREDRAW = 0x000B,
            WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C,
            WM_GETTEXT = 0x000D,
            WM_GETTEXTLENGTH = 0x000E,
            WM_PAINT = 0x000F,
            WM_CLOSE = 0x0010,

            WM_QUIT = 0x0012,
            WM_ERASEBKGND = 0x0014,
            WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE = 0x0015,
            WM_SHOWWINDOW = 0x0018,

            WM_ACTIVATEAPP = 0x001C,

            WM_SETCURSOR = 0x0020,
            WM_MOUSEACTIVATE = 0x0021,
            WM_GETMINMAXINFO = 0x24,
            WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING = 0x0046,
            WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED = 0x0047,

            WM_CONTEXTMENU = 0x007B,
            WM_STYLECHANGING = 0x007C,
            WM_STYLECHANGED = 0x007D,
            WM_DISPLAYCHANGE = 0x007E,
            WM_GETICON = 0x007F,
            WM_SETICON = 0x0080,

            // non client area
            WM_NCCREATE = 0x0081,
            WM_NCDESTROY = 0x0082,
            WM_NCCALCSIZE = 0x0083,
            WM_NCHITTEST = 0x84,
            WM_NCPAINT = 0x0085,
            WM_NCACTIVATE = 0x0086,

            WM_GETDLGCODE = 0x0087,

            WM_SYNCPAINT = 0x0088,

            // non client mouse
            WM_NCMOUSEMOVE = 0x00A0,
            WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1,
            WM_NCLBUTTONUP = 0x00A2,
            WM_NCLBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A3,
            WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A4,
            WM_NCRBUTTONUP = 0x00A5,
            WM_NCRBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A6,
            WM_NCMBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A7,
            WM_NCMBUTTONUP = 0x00A8,
            WM_NCMBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x00A9,

            // keyboard
            WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100,
            WM_KEYUP = 0x0101,
            WM_CHAR = 0x0102,

            WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x0112,

            // menu
            WM_INITMENU = 0x0116,
            WM_INITMENUPOPUP = 0x0117,
            WM_MENUSELECT = 0x011F,
            WM_MENUCHAR = 0x0120,
            WM_ENTERIDLE = 0x0121,
            WM_MENURBUTTONUP = 0x0122,
            WM_MENUDRAG = 0x0123,
            WM_MENUGETOBJECT = 0x0124,
            WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP = 0x0125,
            WM_MENUCOMMAND = 0x0126,

            WM_CHANGEUISTATE = 0x0127,
            WM_UPDATEUISTATE = 0x0128,
            WM_QUERYUISTATE = 0x0129,

            // mouse
            WM_MOUSEFIRST = 0x0200,
            WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
            WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
            WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
            WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0203,
            WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
            WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205,
            WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0206,
            WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207,
            WM_MBUTTONUP = 0x0208,
            WM_MBUTTONDBLCLK = 0x0209,
            WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
            WM_MOUSELAST = 0x020D,

            WM_ENTERMENULOOP = 0x0211,
            WM_EXITMENULOOP = 0x0212,

            WM_NEXTMENU = 0x0213,
            WM_SIZING = 0x0214,
            WM_CAPTURECHANGED = 0x0215,
            WM_MOVING = 0x0216,

            WM_ENTERSIZEMOVE = 0x0231,
            WM_EXITSIZEMOVE = 0x0232,

            WM_MOUSELEAVE = 0x02A3,
            WM_MOUSEHOVER = 0x02A1,
            WM_NCMOUSEHOVER = 0x02A0,
            WM_NCMOUSELEAVE = 0x02A2,

            WM_MDIACTIVATE = 0x0222,
            WM_HSCROLL = 0x0114,
            WM_VSCROLL = 0x0115,

            WM_SYSMENU = 0x313,

            WM_PRINT = 0x0317,
            WM_PRINTCLIENT = 0x0318,
        }

        public struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;

            public RECT(int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
            {
                this.left = left;
                this.top = top;
                this.right = right;
                this.bottom = bottom;
            }

            public static RECT FromXYWH(int x, int y, int width, int height)
            {
                return new RECT(x,
                                y,
                                x + width,
                                y + height);
            }
        }

        internal struct WINDOWPOS
        {
            internal IntPtr hwnd;
            internal IntPtr hWndInsertAfter;
            internal int x;
            internal int y;
            internal int cx;
            internal int cy;
            internal uint flags;
        }

        public struct POINTS
        {
            public short X;
            public short Y;
        }

        public enum WindowStyle
        {
            WS_MAXIMIZE = 0x01000000,
            WS_MINIMIZE = 0x20000000,
        }

        public struct APPBARDATA
        {
            public int cbSize; // initialize this field using: Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(APPBARDATA));
            public IntPtr hWnd;
            public uint uCallbackMessage;
            public uint uEdge;
            public RECT rc;
            public int lParam;
        }

        public struct MARGINS
        {
            public int left;
            public int right;
            public int top;
            public int bottom;
        }


        public static class NativeMethods
        {
            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int SetWindowRgn(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn, bool bRedraw);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
            public static extern bool IsWindowVisible(IntPtr hWnd);

            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern IntPtr CreateRectRgn(int nLeftRect, int nTopRect, int nRightRect, int nBottomRect);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int GetWindowRgn(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hRgn);

            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern int GetRgnBox(IntPtr hrgn, out RECT lprc);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern Int32 GetWindowLong(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 Offset);

            [DllImport("user32.dll")]
            public static extern int GetSystemMetrics(int smIndex);


            [DllImport("shell32.dll")]
            public static extern int SHAppBarMessage(uint dwMessage, [In] ref APPBARDATA pData);

            [DllImport("gdi32.dll")]
            public static extern bool DeleteObject(IntPtr hObj);
        }

        public static class NativeConstants
        {
            public const int SM_CXSIZEFRAME = 32;
            public const int SM_CYSIZEFRAME = 33;
            public const int SM_CXPADDEDBORDER = 92;

            public const int GWL_ID = (-12);
            public const int GWL_STYLE = (-16);
            public const int GWL_EXSTYLE = (-20);

            public const int WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN = 0x00A1;
            public const int WM_NCRBUTTONUP = 0x00A5;

            public const uint TPM_LEFTBUTTON = 0x0000;
            public const uint TPM_RIGHTBUTTON = 0x0002;
            public const uint TPM_RETURNCMD = 0x0100;

            public static readonly IntPtr TRUE = new IntPtr(1);
            public static readonly IntPtr FALSE = new IntPtr(0);

            public const uint ABM_GETSTATE = 0x4;
            public const int ABS_AUTOHIDE = 0x1;
        }


        protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {

            switch (m.Msg)
            {
                case (int)WindowMessages.WM_NCCALCSIZE:
                    {
                        WmNCCalcSize(ref m);
                        break;
                    }
                case (int)WindowMessages.WM_NCACTIVATE:
                    {
                        WmNCActivate(ref m);
                        break;
                    }
                case (int)WindowMessages.WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED:
                    {
                        WmWindowPosChanged(ref m);
                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        base.WndProc(ref m);
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }


        private void SetWindowRegion(IntPtr hwnd, int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
        {
            var rgn = NativeMethods.CreateRectRgn(0, 0, 0, 0);
            var hrg = new HandleRef((object)this, rgn);
            var r = NativeMethods.GetWindowRgn(hwnd, hrg.Handle);
            RECT box;
            NativeMethods.GetRgnBox(hrg.Handle, out box);
            if (box.left != left || box.top != top || box.right != right || box.bottom != bottom)
            {
                var hr = new HandleRef((object)this, NativeMethods.CreateRectRgn(left, top, right, bottom));
                NativeMethods.SetWindowRgn(hwnd, hr.Handle, NativeMethods.IsWindowVisible(hwnd));
            }
            NativeMethods.DeleteObject(rgn);
        }

        private FormWindowState MinMaxState
        {
            get
            {
                var s = NativeMethods.GetWindowLong(Handle, NativeConstants.GWL_STYLE);
                var max = (s & (int)WindowStyle.WS_MAXIMIZE) > 0;
                if (max) return FormWindowState.Maximized;
                var min = (s & (int)WindowStyle.WS_MINIMIZE) > 0;
                if (min) return FormWindowState.Minimized;
                return FormWindowState.Normal;
            }
        }

        private void WmWindowPosChanged(ref Message m)
        {
            DefWndProc(ref m);
            UpdateBounds();
            var pos = (WINDOWPOS)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(WINDOWPOS));
            SetWindowRegion(m.HWnd, 0, 0, pos.cx, pos.cy);
            m.Result = NativeConstants.TRUE;
        }

        private void WmNCCalcSize(ref Message m)
        {

            var r = (RECT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(m.LParam, typeof(RECT));
            var max = MinMaxState == FormWindowState.Maximized;

            if (max)
            {
                var x = NativeMethods.GetSystemMetrics(NativeConstants.SM_CXSIZEFRAME);
                var y = NativeMethods.GetSystemMetrics(NativeConstants.SM_CYSIZEFRAME);
                var p = NativeMethods.GetSystemMetrics(NativeConstants.SM_CXPADDEDBORDER);
                var w = x + p;
                var h = y + p;

                r.left += w;
                r.top += h;
                r.right -= w;
                r.bottom -= h;

                var appBarData = new APPBARDATA();
                appBarData.cbSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(APPBARDATA));
                var autohide = (NativeMethods.SHAppBarMessage(NativeConstants.ABM_GETSTATE, ref appBarData) & NativeConstants.ABS_AUTOHIDE) != 0;
                if (autohide) r.bottom -= 1;

                Marshal.StructureToPtr(r, m.LParam, true);
            }

            m.Result = IntPtr.Zero;
        }

        private void WmNCActivate(ref Message msg)
        {
            // http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/default.asp?url=/library/en-us/winui/winui/windowsuserinterface/windowing/windows/windowreference/windowmessages/wm_ncactivate.asp

            bool active = (msg.WParam == NativeConstants.TRUE);

            if (MinMaxState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
                DefWndProc(ref msg);
            else
            {
                // repaint title bar
                //PaintNonClientArea(msg.HWnd, (IntPtr)1);

                // allow to deactivate window
                msg.Result = NativeConstants.TRUE;
            }
        }


        protected override CreateParams CreateParams
        {
            get
            {
                CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;

                const int WS_MINIMIZEBOX = 0x00020000;
                const int WS_SIZEBOX = 0x00040000;
                const int WS_CAPTION = 0x00C00000;

                cp.Style = cp.Style | WS_MINIMIZEBOX | WS_SIZEBOX | WS_CAPTION;

                return cp;
            }
        }


        protected override void OnHandleCreated(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnHandleCreated(e);

            if (!DesignMode)
                SetWindowRegion(Handle, 0, 0, Width, Height);
        }


        private void DrawShadow(int ShadowWidth)
        {

            var v = 2;
            DwmSetWindowAttribute(Handle, 2, ref v, 4);
            var margins = new MARGINS
            {
                top = ShadowWidth,
                left = ShadowWidth,
                right = ShadowWidth,
                bottom = ShadowWidth
            };
            DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(Handle, ref margins);
        }



        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            DrawShadow(10);

        }

    }
}
```

This is my code, I was hoping you could help me point out the code error or give me an idea
I really want to shadow and WS_SIZEBOX, WS_CAPTION style
How can I get what I want?  Thank you again

Comment: Add a Panel to the Form and then put all the controls into the Panel.  The Panel will have a border.

Comment: @jdweng The border effect is not what I want, the shadow effect is what works best for me.
Or is there a way to make a Panel have shadows?

Comment: The Panel will handle the resize issue.

Comment: @jdweng resize has been handled in other ways. All that's left is the shadow
Glad to hear from you. Thank you

Comment: Maybe the right way of handling resizing is to use a Panel.